# Error : System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I am using Visual Studio 2010/Frawework 3.5. if my listview is vacuum, I receive this error:

> Provide value on **'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception**

on this line:

```
<polirisListView:PolirisGridViewColumn Width="*"  />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ...and exception (inner exception) is?

Comment: How about some more details

Comment: inner exception : The string ' * ' can not be converted into Length

Answer (score 1):

If PolirisGridViewColumn inherits from GridViewColumn check the documentation for GridViewColumnWidth. The value is expected to be a double or the keyword "Auto"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms592684(v=vs.110).aspx

I think you're getting width parameter mixed with DataGridColumn Width which is of type DataGridLength

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much Origence